# Storyboard Deleted by Git and "You need to resolve your current index first" error with Xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, git, merge, branch

I have been working with branches to test out new features with my app, using Xcode 5. Everything has always worked. I just merged from one branch to another and Xcode crashed during that time.

Now, my storyboard has the "d" symbol next to it and if I run it, it still works, but if I make a change and commit, I get a message saying "cannot commit during merge", but the merge was completed because I went back to the lower branch, made a change and that got merged into the upper branch (where I'm now getting this error).

If I try to create a new branch, I get an error saying "You need to resolve your current index first"

My git status is in the screenshot below :

[image]

I'm somewhat new to Git (I've been using it for months but never had to troubleshoot). I need to be careful here because I don't want my storyboard deleted!

Any assistance on this would be really great.